# Google Auth sign in profile given name and family name empty when authenticating laravel 5.4 with Socialite

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, google-signin

I am using Google Auth sign in and fetching profile details. Using

"laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
"laravel/socialite": "^3.0",

and after google login, profile given name and family name empty when authenticating

in my controller:

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider, Request $request)
{
    $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
    dd($user);
}
```

Output Array:

```
+user: array:7 [▼
"kind" => "plus#person"
"etag" => ""ZGQDP-uTLk7k5mmx0bFwLwF_x1M/62FIGh3iMH_OETmP9xVIbfm2ELI""
"emails" => array:1 [▶]
"id" => "103785845060125018193"
"displayName" => ""
"name" => array:2 [▼
  "familyName" => ""
  "givenName" => ""
]
"image" => array:2 [▼
  "url" => "https://<path>/photo.jpg"
  "isDefault" => true
]
```

]